# Implement an autocomplete textbox that is efficient with large database in vb.net?

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

In a Windows application, I'm experiencing performance issues when populating autocompletestring Collection with a large number of items (appr. 60000). Retrieving the data from the database to a datatable is quick enough(< 1 sec), but populating the Collection is much slower since I am iterating through a datatable to fill the collection. Is there a quicker way to perform this operation. I'm populating like this:

```
    Private Sub txtName_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles txtName.KeyDown
    If txtName.TextLength = 2 And e.KeyCode <> Keys.Back Then
        DataCollection.Clear()
        pObjDT = pobjDB.GetDT("Select Name from partymaster where AgentRef ='" & txtAgent.Text & "' And  Name LIKE '" & txtName.Text & "%' ")
        If Not pObjDT Is Nothing Then
            For Each lObjDataRow As DataRow In pObjDT.Rows
                DataCollection.Add(lObjDataRow.Item(0))
            Next
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you define what is the type of control "DataCollection"  are you using

Comment: DataCollection is a type of AutoCompleteStringCollection

Answer (score 1):

Why you query so big collection for autocomplete? I would query something like top 10 or 20 like

```
Select top 10 Name from partymaster where AgentRef ='" & txtAgent.Text & "' And  Name LIKE '" & txtName.Text & "%
```

Comment: As i type along i need to display the suggestion if it exists in the memory

Comment: Ok, Have you tried to use stringbuilder instead of this collection? It should be faster   http://www.dotnetperls.com/stringbuilder-vbnet

Comment: the time consuming part is when iteration through the datatable to fill datacollection. is there any way so that i can point auto complete source as the datatable.

Comment: As far as i understand this function is run every time there's a key press so its not using autocomplete from memory. I would still query for top results every time key is pressed

Comment: DataCollection is set as the autocomplete datasource . I have coded such a way that auto complete suggestions are fetched from db only the corresponding textbox's length = 2

Comment: Why dont you change it then so that "If txtName.TextLength > 1 And e.KeyCode <> Keys.Back Then " and  pObjDT = pobjDB.GetDT("Select  TOP 10 Name from partymaster where AgentRef ='" & txtAgent.Text & "' And  Name LIKE '" & txtName.Text & "%' ")

Comment: that  won't work if the the code is triggered in keydown event, when a new new character is entered it doesn't show suggestion instead it performs the db hit

Comment: This DB hit is normal, its better to make small querys than retrieve large datasets. I dont know why it doesn't populate autocomplete. There must be some way to reload this

Comment: Maybe this will work if you add it end of sub                                               txtName.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
txtName.AutoCompleteCustomSource = DataCollection
txtName.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest

Comment: Agree with this answer, combined with changing the If condition to `If txtName.TextLength > 1 And e.KeyCode <> Keys.Back Then`

Answer (score 0):

Check if `AddRange()` is more efficient than for each:

```
Dim theStrings As String() = pObjDT.AsEnumerable().Select(Function(therow)
                                                             Return therow(0).ToString()
                                                          End Function).ToArray()
 DataCollection.AddRange(theStrings)
```

Comment: i am working on .net 2 AsEnumerable(), is not available

Comment: Ok. Most likely it is not much more efficient anyway, but thought it worth a try.